# C# using PDFsharp

Tags: c#

I am trying to create pdf's from my Visual Studio 2013 C# program.

I have downloaded PDFsharp and now have the folders and files as pictured:

[[image: enter image description here]]

Where do I put these files and what do I do with them?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on solution name in Solution Explorer in Visual Studio;
2. Choose 'Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...';
3. Under Browse tab, search PDFSharp;
4. Install whatever version into the projects you choose;
5. Now you could use them by adding `using PdfSharp.*;`.